# Concatenate then Reverse Concatenate

Tags: sql, ms-access, sas

I'm using the following datafile which contains multiple records per person and multiple values that are specified level 1-5 within the 'clinical event result' column-it looks something like this:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Pat_ID |                            Clinical Event Result                             |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | Triage and Initial RN Assessment [level 1], Vital signs monitoring [level 3] |
|      1 | Trauma [Level 4], Consult/s (Social work, Psych, CXhild Life [Level 4]       |
|      1 | Admission or O.R. preparation [level 5],                                     |
|      2 | Triage and Initial RN Assessment only [level 1]                              |
|      2 | Oral Meds [level 1]                                                          |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm seeking advice to write a code that would result in the output showing only one record per `Pat_ID` to create individual columns whenever a **level** appears within the `Clinical Event Result` column.

For example for the individual with `Pat_ID=1`, I would want the output to appear as so:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Pat_ID  |  Level 1  | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 | Level 4 |  Level 5  |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1       | Triage... | null    | Vitals  | Trauma  | CXLife  | Admission |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

I think first I need to transpose the data so there would be multiple `clinical event result` columns per individual patient row and then concatenate those columns into one column. Second, parse out each level so that each gets its own column.

Ive been using the following code but it only grabs the first value within the `clinical event result` column. For example if there are two `level 4` events, it will only grab the first one and place that in the `level 4` column.

Note, when looking at this code and my example above, I am calling `Financial_Number` the `PAT_ID` for patient privacy purposes.

```
USE EMTCQIData

SELECT FCT.[Financial Number], FCT.[Clinical Event Result], FCT.Level_5, FCT.Level_4, FCT.Level_3, CPT.CPT, MAX_FCT.MAX_FCT_CHARGE
FROM CPT_MASTER as CPT 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT [Financial Number], [Clinical Event Result],

CASE
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%1:1 Nursing care%' Then '1:1 Nursing Care'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Admission or O.R. preparation%' Then 'Admission/OR Preparation'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Airway Management (BLS/ALS interventions)%' Then 'Airway Management'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Critical care transport preparation%' Then 'Critical care transport preparation'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Medical/code alert%' Then 'Medical/code alert'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%O2 therapy%' Then 'O2 therapy'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Pain management with reassessment%' Then 'Pain management with reassessment'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory monitoring%' Then 'Respiratory monitoring'
END Level_5,

CASE
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Respiratory assessment%' Then 'Respiratory assessment'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Patient transport X-ray/CT%' Then 'Patient transport X-ray/CT'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Pulse oximetery%' Then 'Pulse oximetery'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Cardiac monitoring%' Then 'Cardiac monitoring'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Neurological monitoring%' Then 'Neurological monitoring'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Wound Care (less than 15 min)%' Then 'Wound Care (less than 15 min)'
END Level_4,

CASE
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Blood-peripheral venous%' Then 'Blood-peripheral venous'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Urine-catheterized%' Then 'Urine-catheterized'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Oral hydration interventions%' Then 'Oral hydration interventions'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Oral meds%' Then 'Oral meds'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Medication teaching%' Then 'Medication teaching'
       WHEN [Clinical Event Result] like '%Vital signs monitoring%' Then 'Vital signs monitoring'

END Level_3

FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

) 

as FCT ON FCT.[Financial Number]=CPT.FIN
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT [Financial Number] as Fin, MAX(Charge_Code) as MAX_FCT_CHARGE

FROM ED_FCT_Q1_FY19

GROUP BY [Financial Number]

) as MAX_FCT on CPT.Fin = MAX_FCT.Fin
WHERE (FCT.[Clinical Event Result] like '%Level%' or FCT.[Clinical Event Result] like '%level%') AND CPT.CPT LIKE '9928%'
```

Comment: Hi Greg, are you using both SAS and SQL?? , if you are using SAS after extracting data from database, then you can concatenate the strings grouping them by pat_id and then with some tweaking and substring , the required variables can be created.. see the sample code below:

Comment: hi @rhythm thank you so much for your timely response! I have the option to use both SAS and SQL. I'm importing this data from an excel file and not using datalines - how would that change your SAS code?   The worked beautifully, btw!

Comment: @Rhythm the code you provided left me with two columns with the PAT_ID and STR; whre the STR column now contains all of the event_res, how would I segregate these columns based on level ([level 1-5]) thus creating new columns for every event_res level? thanks again!

Comment: Great!! if you are reading data from Excel file, then you can read it using proc import instead of datalines.

Comment: @Rhythm If you have time, It would also be helpful if you could please add additional comments of what is being one at each step:  if first.pat_id then str=event_res; 
  else str=catx('@',str,event_res); /*Concatenate String and use @ or any other     symbol to identify the Levels*/
  str=TRANWRD(str,'],',']@') ;

  if last.pat_id;
  str="@"||str;

  drop event_res;
run;

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: @Rhythm, you're amazing, thank you so much. Is there anyway I can leave a review for your phenomenal help?

Comment: Greg, thanks for your comment :) happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code is in SAS

```
data clinical;
length event_res /*level1 level2 level3 level4 level5*/ $100.;
input pat_id 1. event_res &;

datalines;
1|Triage and Initial RN Assessment [level 1], Vital signs monitoring [level 3]|
1|Trauma [Level 4], Consult/s (Social work, Psych, CXhild Life [Level 4]
1|Admission or O.R. preparation [level 5],
2|Triage and Initial RN Assessment only [level 1]
2| Oral Meds [level 1]
;
run;

proc sort data=clinical; by pat_id; run;

data clinical1;
length str $300;
 set clinical;
  by pat_id;
  retain str "";

  if first.pat_id then str=event_res; /*For Every first entry of a PAT_ID, the string is the first available Event Result and for next entries it is concatenated*/
  else str=catx('@',str,event_res); /*Concatenate String and use @ or any other symbol to identify the Levels*/
  str=TRANWRD(str,'],',']@') ; /*Convert/transalte ], into ]@ just to better differentiate the Levels*/

  if last.pat_id; /*Keep only the the Last entry per Pat_Id after concatenation, because at last entry we will have full combined string*/

  /*Add @ at begin and end to mark the boundaries*/
  str="@"||str;
  if substr(str,length(str),1) ne "@" then str1=str||"@";
  else str1=str;

  cnt=count(str1,'@');

  drop event_res str;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select max(cnt)-1 into: max_cnt from clinical1;
quit;

%let max_cnt1=&max_cnt;

data clinical2;
 set clinical1;
/*Define array of variables*/
  array vars{&max_cnt1} $100. var_1-var_&max_cnt1;

  i=1;
  do while (i<=cnt-1);
    vars{i}=scan(str1,i,'@');
    i=i+1;
  end;

  array level{5} $100. lvl_1-lvl_5;
  do i = 1 to 5;
    if find(upcase(vars{i}),"LEVEL 1")>0 then level{1}=catx('#',level{1},vars{i});
    if find(upcase(vars{i}),"LEVEL 2")>0 then level{2}=catx('#',level{2},vars{i});
    if find(upcase(vars{i}),"LEVEL 3")>0 then level{3}=catx('#',level{3},vars{i});
    if find(upcase(vars{i}),"LEVEL 4")>0 then level{4}=catx('#',level{4},vars{i});
    if find(upcase(vars{i}),"LEVEL 5")>0 then level{5}=catx('#',level{5},vars{i});
  end;
drop cnt var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4 var_5 i; 
run;
```